# Cakephp 3: what are the best pratices to manage translation exceptions in views?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

In April '18, phpDocs has been updated for all @throws (good idea) including I18n::getTranslator.

Now all views using __() functions get a warning in the IDE (always normal).

But, what are the best practices to manage that kind of warning in a view ?

It does not seem a good idea to add a try/catch, nor to overload the __() function.

The @throws directive would be interesting but it does not work in a view.

Any idea ?

Comment: This has already been reverted for the I18n functions: **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/12361**

Comment: Thanks @npm ! I didn't think a minute to a revert after 3 months. The case does not seem so obvious to treat after reading the issue https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/12346